# Sentry prevents my Next.js application build

Tags: next.js, sentry

I recently added sentry to my nextjs project. My problem is this error prevents my application to get build. I have the same error on run time as well but what baffles me is why is it preventing my application to build. Can I config this in a way that only works on runtime?

```
Failed to compile.

Sentry CLI Plugin: Command failed: D:\client-new\node_modules\@sentry\cli\sentry-cli.exe releases new SOME_KEY_CODE
error: API request failed
  caused by: [28] Timeout was reached (Failed to connect to sentry.io port 443 after 21064 ms: Timed out)

Add --log-level=[info|debug] or export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=[info|debug] to see more output.
Please attach the full debug log to all bug reports.

Sentry CLI Plugin: Command failed: D:\client-new\node_modules\@sentry\cli\sentry-cli.exe releases new SOME_KEY_CODE
error: API request failed
  caused by: [28] Timeout was reached (Failed to connect to sentry.io port 443 after 21053 ms: Timed out)

Add --log-level=[info|debug] or export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=[info|debug] to see more output.
Please attach the full debug log to all bug reports.


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

I'm using Next.js 12 and sentry/nextjs 7.28.1
and I see this error on both local and server while build.

Comment: try reading through the discussion [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/issues/1232) in GitHub, I believe it's a similar situation that have possible workarounds.

Comment: I have the same problem. It works fine if we build it in the gitlab pipeline, but if I build it locally, I get sentry timeout errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Sentry to only work at runtime by conditionally importing the Sentry library using an environment variable on both `sentry.server.config.js` and `sentry.client.config.js`.

##### Example:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && process.env.SENTRY_DSN) {
  const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');
  Sentry.init({ dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DSN });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately I'm getting the same error even after setting this config.